# Silverlight 4 Drag and Drop Alternatives

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-4.0

I want to add the ability to drag a user control from one part of a Silverlight 4 page onto another user control on the same page (not talking about the new Silverlight 4 ability to drag a file from the OS onto the page).

What approach is most straightforward?  What approach offers the most flexibility?

Here are some alternatives I found so far

- [SO drag-and-drop-control-for-silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829768/drag-and-drop-control-for-silverlight).  Same question but answers apply to SL 2.
- [Alex van Beek's DragManager](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2009/09/07/A-complete-Silverlight-3-drag-and-drop-solution.aspx).  Written for SL3.
- [Silverlight Drag Drop](http://silverlightdragdrop.codeplex.com/).  Also written for SL3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't compare all of the options you've listed but if I wanted to implement control to control drag drop feature I would the `DragDrop` and the `DragDropTarget` classes from the Silveright Toolkit.  Its the only DragDrop framework I know of that has been refreshed for SL4 and if you already use elements from the Toolkit  then that would be a natural solution.