# Silverlight Drag and drop for any UIElement?

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, uielement

I see a great deal of writing about Silverlight 4's support for drag and drop. However, it is all about files. I want to just make normal user controls draggable. Is this possible, or is it limited to files?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add drag-and-drop capabilities to any element of you Silverlight application - it is not limited to files (this just became easier in 4.0). Using attached behaviors and some drag-and-drop management code you should be able to achieve the interaction need. Without knowing exactly what you hope to accomplish, my best advice would be to go check out some projects like:

http://silverlightdragdrop.codeplex.com/

and read about the discussion here:

[Silverlight 4 Drag and Drop Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762707/silverlight-4-drag-and-drop-alternatives)